# Assign multiple strings to unique string C# MultiMap, Dictionary or another method?

Tags: c#, string, dictionary

The issue I have at the moment is that I currently have two strings which contain data that can be used to match them to one another. This data is a IP source address and an IP destination address. 
What I am trying to do is match up the IP source to all of its destination addresses. The current code I have at the moment looks like this.

```
 var xmlDoc2 = new XmlDocument();
 xmlDoc2.Load(textBox1.Text);
 HashSet<string> hs = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
 var node = xmlDoc2.SelectNodes("pdml/packet/proto[@name='ip']/@showname");

   foreach (XmlAttribute attribute1 in node)
   {
     string ip = attribute1.Value;
     var arr = ip.Split(); var src = arr[5]; var dst = arr[8];
     if (hs.Contains(src))
     {
      string ipsrc = src;
      string ipdst = dst;
      listBoxDST.Items.Add(ipdst);
     }
     else
     {
      hs.Add(src);
      string ipdst = dst;
      string ipsrc = src;
      listBoxSRC.Items.Add(ipsrc);
      listBoxDST.Items.Add(ipdst);
      }
   }
```

I have looked at MultiMapping but that is only used in C++(again, correct me if I'm wrong).

I also looked at dictionaries, could it be best to store the ipdst as a list and add it to a key(ipsrc). I can't seem to figure out how to make it work that way because of the if statement for the hashset. (Code above is without the failed implementation of the dictionary.

Would it be better if I made a database in Access to use as a storage? or is there some way whereby I could have a Unique Source Address with a list of Destination Addresses?

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented a `Dictionary` version of your code.

Try this out:

```
var xmlDoc2 = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc2.Load(textBox1.Text);
Dictionary<string, List<string>> hs = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

var node = xmlDoc2.SelectNodes("pdml/packet/proto[@name='ip']/@showname");

foreach (XmlAttribute attribute1 in node)
{
    string ip = attribute1.Value;
    var arr = ip.Split(); var src = arr[5]; var dst = arr[8];

    List<string> l;
    if (!hs.TryGetValue(src, out l))
    {
        hs[src] = l = new List<string>();
    }

    l.Add(dst);
}
```

It uses `TryGetValue` to check if there is already an key in that dictionary. It's adds a list if the ip address doesn't exist.